# Validar un Checkbox con JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Quisiera saber la manera de validar un `Checkbox` con `JQuery` en un pequeño formulario.

```html
<form action="">
  <a>Correo: </a>
  <input type="email" name="correo">
  <br>
  <a>Telefono: </a>
  <input type="text" name="telefono">
  <br>
  <a>Aceptar condiciones: </a>
  <input type="checkbox" name="aceptar">
  <br>
  <button type="submit" id="submit">Enviar Formulario</button>
</form>
```

Encontré varios tipos de validaciones `.is(selector)`y `.prop()` pero traté de aplicarlos y no lo logré conseguir, únicamente quiero que arroje un alert que diga algo como **Acepta las condiciones**.

Comment: asociación: https://stackoverflow.com/q/901712/1983854

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Cuando usas `is()` tienes que usar el selector [`:checked`](https://api.jquery.com/checked-selector/):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#submit").on("click", function() {
        var condiciones = $("#aceptar").is(":checked");
        if (!condiciones) {
            alert("Debe aceptar las condiciones");
            event.preventDefault();
        }
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.2.min.js"></script>
<form action="">
    <div>
        <p>Correo: </p>
        <input type="email" name="correo" id="correo">
    </div>
    <div>
        <p>Telefono: </p>
        <input type="text" name="telefono" id="telefono">
    </div>
    <div>
        <p>Aceptar condiciones: </p>
        <input type="checkbox" name="aceptar" id="aceptar">
    </div>
    <button type="submit" id="submit">Enviar Formulario </button>
</form>
```

Cuando no se han marcado las condiciones debes usar [`event.preventDefault()`](https://api.jquery.com/event.preventdefault/) para evitar que el formulario haga el `post`.

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta amigo, me resulto las mas adecuada para mi proyecto.

Comment: De nada @EduardoJavierMaldonado que bueno que te haya servido

Answer (score 3):

Podrias implementar algo como ser

```js
$(function(){
  $("#submit").click(function(event){
        var seleccion = $("#aceptar")[0].checked;
        if(!seleccion){
            event.preventDefault();
            alert("Acepta las condiciones");
        }
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form action="">
<a>Correo: </a><input type="email" name="correo"><br>
<a>Telefono: </a><input type="text" name="telefono"><br>
<a>Aceptar condiciones: </a><input type="checkbox" name="aceptar" id="aceptar" ><br>
<button type="submit" id="submit">Enviar Formulario </button>
</form>
```

Tambien hay otras alternativas como ser

```
var seleccion = $("#aceptar").is(':checked');
```

Answer (score 2):

Solo pregunta si esta checkeado con `.is(':checked')`:

```
$('form').on('submit', function(){
    if($("input[type='checkbox']").is(':checked') === true)
    console.log('Soy valido')
  else{
  console.log('Soy invalido')
    return false; //Soy invalid
  } 
})
```

[DEMO en vivo](https://jsfiddle.net/8qx56wb9/)

Answer (score 1):

Puedes hacer uso de "required" y así no tienes que usar JavaScript, aunque el mensaje mostrado dependerá del navegador.

`<input type="checkbox" name="aceptar" required>`

Comment: De echo estaba usando el required pero no me agrada por tal motivo pedí ayuda para poder hacerlo con jquery ya que asi me lo pidio mi cliente y no lo hice funcionar por pequeños errores no andaba tan perdido.